# I would like to filter pings

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to filter my pings so that I only see the IP addresses which are not online. I tried to use the findstr but it does not outprint the ip address.

Comment: You forgot to post the code you already have

Comment: I would use test-connection or test-netconnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bit complex construction than Wander Nauta, but you have a room to change things.

Put your IPs in `C:\tmp\ips.txt` splitted with new line like:

```
192.168.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.2.3.4
```

And start script:

```
Clear-Host
$ips = Get-Content "C:\tmp\ips.txt"
foreach($ip in $ips) {
    if(Test-Connection $ip -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        #Write-Output "Alive ip - $ip"
    } else {
        Write-Output "Dead ip - $ip"
    }
}
```

The result will be: `Dead ip - 1.2.3.4`

Answer (score 1):

The `Test-Connection` cmdlet returns `PingStatus` objects that can be filtered with `Where-Object`, like so:

```
Test-Connection -Count 1 -TargetName 1.1.1.1,8.8.4.4,192.0.2.1 |
    Where-Object Status -ne Success
```

That would show for example:

```
   Destination: 192.0.2.1

Ping Source           Address                   Latency BufferSize Status
                                                   (ms)        (B)
---- ------           -------                   ------- ---------- ------
   1 b7e517d72826     *                               *          * TimedOut
```

If you want to see only the destination address, you can add  `| Select-Object Destination`.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection)